# add 2 buttons to this sketch

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, stepper-driver, code

Can anyone tell me how to add 2 button switches to this sketch (one forward and one reverse) for a second motor?` This code works great and I would like to just add the some button switches to pins 4 and 5.  I tried to just add switches to pin A1 and gnd or 5v but it does not work.

```
#include <AccelStepper.h> // accelstepper library
AccelStepper stepper(1, 8, 9); // direction Digital 9 (CCW), pulses Digital 8 (CLK)

//Pins
const byte Analog_X_pin = A1; // x-axis readings
const byte enablePin = 7;

//Variables
int Analog_X = 0;             //x-axis value
int Analog_X_AVG = 0;         //x-axis value average
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
  //PINS
  pinMode(Analog_X_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(enablePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP); 
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  InitialValues(); // averaging the values of analog pin 0 (value from potmeter)
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  // Stepper parameters
  // setting up some default values for maximum speed and maximum acceleration
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(2000);     //SPEED = Steps / second  
  stepper.setAcceleration(1000); //ACCELERATION = Steps /(second)^2    
  stepper.setSpeed(1000);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
  ReadAnalog();
  ReadLimits();  
  stepper.runSpeed(); //step the motor (this will step the motor by 1 step at each loop indefinitely)
}

void ReadLimits()
{
  if( digitalRead(2)==LOW && stepper.speed()>0 )//read input, assuming they have pull-up resistors.
  {
    stepper.setSpeed(0);
  }

  if( digitalRead(3)==LOW && stepper.speed()<0 )//read input, assuming they have pull-up resistors.
  {
    stepper.setSpeed(0);
  }
}

void ReadAnalog() {
  if (abs(Analog_X-Analog_X_AVG) > 50) {
    digitalWrite(enablePin, HIGH);  // enable the driver
    stepper.setSpeed(5*(Analog_X-Analog_X_AVG));   
  } else {
    digitalWrite(enablePin, LOW);   // disable the driver
    stepper.setSpeed(0);
  }
  // Reading the potentiometer in the joystick: 
  Analog_X = analogRead(Analog_X_pin);  
  // if the value is 25 "value away" from the average (midpoint), we allow the update of the speed
  // This is a sort of a filter for the inaccuracy of the reading
  if (abs(Analog_X-Analog_X_AVG) > 50) {
    stepper.setSpeed(5 * (Analog_X-Analog_X_AVG));    
  } else {
    stepper.setSpeed(0);
  }
}

void InitialValues() {
  //Set the values to zero before averaging
  float tempX = 0;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  // read the analog 50x, then calculate an average. 
  // they will be the reference values
  for (int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
    tempX += analogRead(Analog_X_pin);  
    delay(10); //allowing a little time between two readings
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  Analog_X_AVG = tempX/50; 
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  Serial.print("AVG_X: ");
  Serial.println(Analog_X_AVG);
  Serial.println("Calibration finished");  
}
```

Comment: what is preventing you from adding the necessary code?

Comment: You've added buttons to pins 4 and 5 but set pull-ups on 2 and 3. Your question is better suited to https://arduino.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't know the necessary code that's what I'm asking, look I'm 66 yrs old, I'm trying to build something to get in and out after my surgery, you don't have to help me.

Comment: @edrummer Don't get offended that easily. It's normal on this website to be questionned, but the other were just trying to help you. If you want help, please be ready to put effort into explaining your problem better if people don't understand it.

Comment: I'm not offended I just want to get this done, I appreciate any help. Code is a foreign language to me. I don't know how to tell the motor to go forward when I press this button, and go backward when I press the other button.

Comment: Try learning basic Arduino programming. There is a plethora of free courses and tutorials.